# What is the Malliavin derivative of $\int_0^T f(B(t))dB(t)$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, malliavin-calculus

> What is the Malliavin derivative of $F=\int_0^T f(B(t))dB(t)$?

I know if $f$ is deterministic, then the Malliavin derivative of $F$ is just $f(t)$. But what if $f$ depends on the path, can we say anything then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is good enough so that everything I'll write is well defined, in that case we have that

$$D_t \int_0^T f(B(s)dB(s)=f(B(t))+\int_t^T f'(B(s))dB(s).$$

This is a particular case of proposition 1.3.8. of [Nualart's book.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-28329-3)